# Regex error Codename one project

Tags: regex, codenameone

I am using the validator class to verify the password TextField using regular expression that makes it have to contain 1 uppercase letter 1 lowercase letter 1 number and 1 symbol and it has to be between 6 and 10 characteres.

```
Validator val = new Validator();
Constraint passconst = new RegexConstraint("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d) 
(?=.*[#$^+=!*()@%&]).{6,10}$", "Password invalid");
val.addConstraint(password, passconst);
```

but I keep getting this error:

com.codename1.util.regex.RESyntaxException: Syntax error: Missing operand to closure

I couldn't figure out the mistake in the regular expressio, it was generated by using this website https://www.regextester.com/97402

Comment: The regex flavor you are using does not support lookaheads.

Comment: how do I change it to support lookaheads? sorry I am new to regular expressions

Comment: I do not know how, but if you have full access to Java code, you may use `java.util.regex` with your pattern.

Comment: that's the problem, with codename one I don't have access to java.util.regex, I was using this in the java app ((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,15}) as pattern but it shows the same error here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find regex too obfuscated to follow you can just do something which I personally find simpler like:

```
private static final String supportedCharacters = "abc...";

Constraint passConstraint = new LengthConstraint(6, "Password invalid") {
   @Override
   public boolean isValid(Object value) {
       String s = (String)v;
       for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
          if(!supportedCharacters.contains(s.charAt(i)) return false;
       }
       return super.isValid(value) 
   }
};
```